# Prevent automatic installation of Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-apps

How can I prevent Windows 8 from installing apps silently?

I've already seen some app related to HP getting installed along with some necessary drivers when I connected a HP printer to the computer, and apps related to my ISP got installed when I got my computer connected to a specific Wi-Fi network. Recently, Xbox One SmartGlass installed itself when it detected an Xbox One on the home network.

Is there any way to prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You might change Windows *Device Installation Settings* (enter Installation in the Search menu). Default is to download drivers automatically, but you can set it to manual.
Also check that *User Account Control* settings (in Action Center) are at least at the second from the top, or set to the highest level of the slider if you want notification for *all* changes, even ones done as if under your own account.